# How to bootstrap terraform state without doing apply

Tags: terraform, devops

I am basically doing restructuring of terraform modules( breaking the monolith) by moving files to different directories etc. In this case i want to bootstrap the state for new directories without applying as those resources are already exist.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one tool for refactoring of TF code automatically. Instead there is a number of guidelines on how to do it in [TF docs](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/refactoring).

Most notably, in the recent TF version v1.1  there is [moved](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/refactoring#moved-block-syntax) block introduced to help with the refactoring procedure. If you use old version of TF, you have to manually use [state mv](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/state/mv) command during the refactoring procedure.